# How can i stop button tkinter python?

Tags: python, tkinter

[When i click two times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFFrs.png)When i click on button the function run again and again i w ant to stop the button from repeat it until i go to another window and make it work again with out repeat, please try the code for more understanding

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Treeview

class App_Win():
    def __init__(self, main_Win):
        self.main_Win = main_Win
        self.main_Win.geometry("1100x650+50+50")
        self.mainFrame = Frame(self.main_Win,background="white")
        self.mainFrame.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="news")
        self.leftFrame = Frame(self.main_Win, background="#007094", width=100)
        self.leftFrame.grid(row=0, column=0,rowspan=3, sticky="nws")
        self.cusBtn = Button(self.leftFrame, text="Customers", cursor="hand",bg="#007094", bd=4,activebackground="#007094", font=("arial",14), command=self.customers)
        self.cusBtn.grid(row=3,column=1,pady=5, sticky="NWES")
    def customers(self):       
        self.customer = Treeview(self.mainFrame,columns=("First Name","Last Name","Phone","Sec Phone","Email","Co Name"))      
        self.customer["show"]="headings"
        self.customer.heading("First Name", text="Firest Name")
        self.customer.pack()
root2 = Tk()
App_Win(root2)
root2.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: button show data from database in a frame when data shows and i click on button again it show data again in the middle of screen so i need when i show data and i click on button again not show data until i open another window, i added pic

Comment: It is because you create new treeview whenever `customers()` is executed. The treeview should be created once.

Comment: it's working when i make customers() have         self.customer.pack() only and create the treeview under     def __init__(self, main_Win):, thanks

Comment: Include all details of the problem. You cannot give the code for us to run and find out the error. Please post the error, your desired output and a full traceback and images (if possible) to show the error visually. This will help us debug